# From where I can change the "app authorization policies"?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have read this article [about App permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219576(office.15).aspx), within the article there is section mention "app authorization policies". From where I can change these policies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to AppManifest.XML file of the App, you will find the option to change the permission

Comment: I don't want to change app permission , but I need to change "authorization policies"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179892.aspx